# Frustrating issue where neither cron nor su -c runs my job (permissions?)

Tags: permissions, cron

**Updated (and [snipped](/posts/31117/revisions)) with more details below.**

I've set up a cron script and I'm trying to debug why it's not running. *[Snipped context testing, which is all ok; [see revision 2](/revisions/31117/2) for details]* The command itself, in case it helps, (arrows indicate line-wrapping for legibility) is:

```bsh
/usr/bin/php -C /etc /path/to/process.php
↪  >>/path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log
```

*[Snipped permissions testing, which is all ok; see below and [revision 2](/revisions/31117/2) for details]*

Checking `crontab` (again, wrapped for legibility), I get:

```bsh
[blackero@XXXXXXXXXXX to]$ sudo crontab -u cronuser -l
MAIL="blackero@localhost"

30 9 * * * cronuser /usr/bin/php -C /etc /path/to/process.php
↪   >>/path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log
20 18 7 * * cronuser /usr/bin/php -C /etc /path/to/process.php
↪   >>/path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log
22 18 7 * * cronuser echo "Test" > /path/to/test.txt
↪   2> /path/to/error.txt
```

**Update #1** at 2012-02-08 12:32 Z

*[Snip: Having tried [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert)'s [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31120/14527) ([revision 3](/revisions/31117/4))]*, I know that the `cronuser` can run the script properly and can write to the two `.log` files. (One of the first things the `process.php` script does is download a file by FTP; it is successfully doing that too.) But, even after fixing the `MAIL=""` line (both by removing it and by changing it to `MAILTO="blackero@localhost"`), the cron task still doesn't run, nor does it send me any email.

A friend suggested that I retry the

```bsh
 9 12 8 * * cronuser /bin/echo "Test" > /var/www/eDialog/test.txt
 ↪  2> /var/www/eDialog/error.txt
```

task, after passing the full path to `/bin/echo`. Having just tried that, it also didn't work and also generated no email, so I'm at a loss.

**Update #2** at 2012-02-08 19:15 Z

[A very useful chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2425) with [oHessling](/users/13999/ohessling), it would seem that the problem is with `pam`. For each time that `cron` has tried to run my job, I have `/var/log/cron` entries:

```bsh
crond[29522]: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
crond[29522]: CRON (cronuser) ERROR: failed to open PAM security session: Success
crond[29522]: CRON (cronuser) ERROR: cannot set security context
```

I fixed that by adding the following line to `/etc/shadow`:

```bsh
cronuser:*:15217:0:99999:7:::
```

As I found [on a forum](http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/PAM-retrieve-authentication-info-ftopict50681.html), if the user does not appear in `/etc/shadow`, then `pam` won't continue processing the security request. Adding `*` as the second column means this user cannot log in with a password (as no hash is specified). Fixing that led to a different error in `/var/log/cron`, so, double-checking my `crontab` I noticed I had specified the username each time.

Correcting that means my `crontab` now reads:

```bsh
[blackero@XXXXXXXXXXX ~]$ sudo crontab -u cronuser -l
MAILTO="blackero@localhost"

30 9 * * * /usr/bin/php -C /etc /path/to/process.php
↪   >>/path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log
52 18 8 * * /usr/bin/php -C /etc /path/to/process.php
↪   >>/path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log
9 12 8 * * /bin/echo "Test" > /path/to/test.txt
↪   2> /path/to/error.txt
```

but now `/var/log/cron` shows me:

```bsh
Feb  8 18:52:01 XXXXXXXXXXX crond[16279]: (cronuser) CMD (/usr/bin/php -C /etc
↪   /path/to/process.php >>/path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log)
```

and nothing comes into the `stdout.log` or the `stderr.log`. No mail was sent to me and none of the other files in `/var/log/` has any entry in the right timeframe, and I'm running out of ideas as to where to look to see what's going wrong

Comment: When you say you put that line in "a cron file", which file in particular? That's the format for a system cron file (e.g., in /etc)—user crontabs don't have the user field.

Comment: I'm just typing a bigger update at the moment, but I noticed that myself (when I solved the `pam` issue, it was really obvious from `/var/log/cron` that this was the case). But I still haven't fixed. it. Update coming within a minute or two.

Comment: @derobert Updated now.

Comment: While nothing gets written to stdout.log and stderr.log, do they get created? If they're being created, then at least that part of the command is working; that'd narrow it down to PHP or the PHP script failing for some reason. In which case (a) make sure PHP is set to flush output (or call `flush`/`ob_flush`); (b) start putting `<?php echo "about to frob" ?>` lines in the script, and see how far it gets; (c) make sure PHP is set to spew errors to stderr—not just some error log (that it may not even have permission to under that user)

Comment: Also, su'd to cronuser, try `echo hello | mail -s 'test message' your-user` and see if that mail goes somewhere useful (just to make sure local mail is working on the box).

Comment: The PHP script worked when I ran it in a minimal shell as `cronuser` earlier in the week (and was sending output to both stdout and stderr before I tweaked it), but I'll try testing `mail` when I get to the office tomorrow; thanks :o)

Comment: Mail is indeed working on the box; having just done my `sudo su -s /bin/sh cronuser` and `echo hello | mail -s 'test message' blackero`, I do end up with a message in my mailbox. The two files `stdout.log` and `stderr.log` already exist (from having run the script in a minimal shell, per [your earlier suggestion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31120/14527)), so I know it's not the PHP script that's the problem; it's something about the configuration of `cron` (presumably). That test also confirmed that the PHP output does go to `stdout` and `stderr`, rather than some other log.

Comment: I've found the problem. And I feel stupid: [see below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31381/14527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The `-C` [command line switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) I'm sending to `php`, which should have been `-c`. I've no idea why `cron` wasn't reporting that to me in *any* manner, let alone a useful manner (or how I somehow managed to get it into the `crontab` with a capital C but test it on the CLI with a lowercase), but running it yet again in the CLI with a colleague here acting as my [monkey](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2010/06/03/first-ask-the-monkey/) and suddenly it was obvious.

Now how stupid do I feel?

Well, at least it's resolved now and `cron` is happily running my damn script. Thank you everyone for all your help.

Comment: You didn't get an error because php doesn't bother to report one. Nice :-(

Comment: Well there was an error somewhere eventually, but it was `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/php /tmp/helloworld.php: No such file or directory`, which is hardly helpful. At least I got the damn thing sorted :)

Answer (score 6):

First off, when a cron job fails, cron sends email. By default, that is to the owner of the cron job. So those emails are probably going to cronuser@localhost or maybe root@localhost. Check those email boxes. Alternatively, you can specify where the mail should go by putting `MAILTO=email@domain` at the top of the crontab file. (Actually, I see you put `MAIL=""` at the top of your crontab. At least according to `man 5 crontab` on my machine, it should be `MAILTO`. And you *don't* want to throw away error messages when trying to figure out why it isn't working!)

Second, cron uses `/bin/sh`. Set `SHELL=/bin/bash` (again, at the top of the crontab) if you need bash extensions.

Third, you haven't fully tested permissions. You need to do something like:

```
# su -s /bin/sh -u cronuser
$ touch /path/to/stdout.log
$ touch /path/to/stderr.log
$ cat /path/to/process.php > /dev/null
$ exit
```

to fully check permissions. `cronuser` could be missing +x on a parent directory, for example. (I guess you should check /usr/bin/php as well, but I assume that's sane)

You can also try running the command in a minimal environment:

```
# su -s /bin/sh -u cronuser
$ env - /bin/sh
$ /usr/bin/php -C /etc /path/to/process.php
```

to see if that works.

Comment: We don't  have a mailserver available to that server at the moment, which is why I'd set `MAIL=""` and was redirecting `stdout` and `stderr`. Will removing the `MAIL` line mean they go to my local mailbox without the lack of an SMTP host being a problem? The lines you give for testing permissions are roughly how I created the two `.log` files, fwiw. Thank you, though; I'll try all of that when I get to the office in the morning.

Comment: Hi @OwenBlacker. cron does not need a mailserver to send e-mails. You have just to loggon as `cronuser` or `root` and run `mail` without parameters. Hope this may help. Let us know... If `/bin/ls -> /bin/bash`, you may not need `SHELL=/bin/bash`. You may also replace `>` by `>>` for file redirection (eg. in `> /path/to/test.txt`) because of `set -C`. Very good answer => +1

Comment: Awesome; I'll check that out in the morning, then. Thank you both.

Comment: Ok, so I've tested it in the minimal environment (with `su -s /bin/sh cronuser` and so on, as in this answer) and it runs ok. It still doesn't run from inside `cron`, though, even after removing the `MAIL=""` line. Frustratingly, it didn't generate any email either. There's no file at `/var/spool/mail/cronuser`, so I tried changing the `MAIL` line to `MAILTO="blackero@localhost"` but that doesn't cause it to run (or send _me_ email) either. I'm still at a loss...

Comment: I've found the problem. And I feel stupid: [see below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31381/14527)

Answer (score 1):

### is `crond` running?

Try one of these commands:

```
pidof crond
pgrep -l crond
ps caxf | grep -6 crond --color
```

output of last command:

```
11881 ? S 0:00 \_ httpd 
11882 ? S 0:00 \_ httpd 
11883 ? S 0:00 \_ httpd 
11884 ? S 0:00 \_ httpd 
11885 ? S 0:00 \_ httpd 
11886 ? S 0:00 \_ httpd 
2098 ? Ss 0:01 crond             #this 'crond' is in red
2125 ? Ss 0:00 sudoscriptd 
2127 ? Ss 0:00 \_ sudoscriptd 
2136 tty2 Ss+ 0:00 mingetty 
2137 tty3 Ss+ 0:00 mingetty 
2138 tty4 Ss+ 0:00 mingetty 
2139 tty5 Ss+ 0:00 mingetty
```

### What is the `crond` configuration?

Check your `/etc/rc.d/init.d` or `/etc/init.d` or whatever start-up file.

The `crond` configuration can list the *denied* or/and *allowed* users.
Is your user *denied*?  Check these files:

```
   /etc/cron.allow
   /etc/cron.deny
```

If both files are absent, only root is *allowed*.
If `cron.allow` is absent and `cron.deny`is empty, then all users are *allowed* by default.

The file `/etc/crontab` must be writeable for root only:

```
$ ls -l /etc/crontab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 255 Jul 15  2006 /etc/crontab
```

### What does `crond` say?

The natural way to receive information from `crond` is local mail. `crond` usually uses `sendmail`. If `sendmail` is not available, it is possible to give another mail command (`CRONDARGS="-mmail"`).

But at this stage, the best is to check directly the `crond` logs (`ll /var/log/cron*`).

### Restart `crond`

The issue may be fixed while restating `crond`...

If the issue is still there, then before another restart let's run it without `init.d` or `service`, and try other options:

sudo crond -p -x sch

And check again `crond` log files...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2425/discussion-between-owen-blacker-and-ohessling)

Comment: From that chat discussion, it looks like the problem is with `pam`. I'll open a new question (referring to this one) in a moment.

Comment: @OwenBlacker: sounds like your cron isn't working at all, and someone else administers the box for you. Have you asked that someone else? He/she/they may know the answer immediately.

Comment: @derobert Unfortunately there's a fine division of responsibilities and they won't help with "application problems". (And they have a long lead time to do anything much.) If I can't get it cracked today or tomorrow, I'll see if I can get anything out of them, but it would be much quicker and easier (politically, for a start) to be able to get it fixed without them.

Comment: I've found the problem. And I feel stupid: [see below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31381/14527)